# Как задать cвой алгоритм сравнения cначала по значению, потом по ключу в Map

Tags: java

допустим у меня есть мапа состоящая из слов и количества их повторений в тексте

```
TreeMap<String,Integer> treeMap = new TreeMap<>();

treeMap.put("CCC", 10);
treeMap.put("KKK", 11);
treeMap.put("AAA", 2);
treeMap.put("BBB", 2);
treeMap.put("DDD", 2);

for(Map.Entry e : treeMap.entrySet()){

    System.out.println(e.getKey()+" "+ e.getValue());
}
```

output:

```
AAA 2
BBB 2
CCC 10
DDD 2
KKK 11
```

Нужно чтобы сначало сортировало по количеству повторений, если слова имеют одинаковое количество повторений, то тогда сортировались в лексикографичном порядке.

must be like:

```
KKK 11
CCC 10
AAA 2
BBB 2
DDD 2
```

Comment: вот сперва ответил, потом проверил на дубли. Но зато у меня компаратор из восьмой явы :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

То, что вы хотите, нельзя сделать только с помощью `TreeMap`, т.к. `TreeMap` задает порядок только по ключу.

Вам нужно посчитать количество повторений, а потом выгрузить все пары в `SortedSet` указав компаратор (или в `List` и вызывать `sort`);

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    map.put( "AAA", 2 );
    map.put( "BBB", 2 );
    map.put( "CCC", 10 );
    map.put( "DDD", 2 );
    map.put( "KKK", 11 );

    System.out.println( map );

    SortedSet<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> sorted = new TreeSet<Map.Entry<String,Integer>>(
            // сортируем сперва по значениям (в natural order, т.е. по возрастанию)
            Comparator.<Map.Entry<String, Integer>, Integer>comparing( Map.Entry::getValue )
                .reversed() // по убыванию
                .thenComparing( Map.Entry::getKey ) // и по ключам по возрастанию
        );

    sorted.addAll( map.entrySet() );

    System.out.println( sorted );
}
```

Comment: Спс, да наверно так

Comment: `Comparator.<Map.Entry<String, Integer>, Integer>comparing( Map.Entry::getValue )` , не могу ток вот этот синтоксис понять почему тут такие странные джинерики, можно поподробнее плз.

Comment: `Comparator.comparing` принимает объект `java.util.Function`, метод `apply` которого вынимает из аргумента (в данном случае `Map.Entry`) поле типа `Comparable`, по которому компаратор будет сравнивать. Почему Eclipse не смог вывести все типы, я пока не могу сказать, попробую позже посмотреть.

Answer (score 2):

Если вы хотите в результате иметь `Map`, лучший вариант — отсортировать записи и скинуть их в `LinkedHashMap` в нужном порядке. `TreeMap` не стоит сортировать с использованием значений, это может привести к психоделическим эффектам. Можно, например, так сделать (Java-8):

```
Map<String, Integer> result = map.entrySet().stream()
        .sorted(Entry.<String, Integer> comparingByValue().reversed()
                .thenComparing(Entry.comparingByKey()))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue, (a, b) -> {
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        }, LinkedHashMap::new));
```

Компаратор у меня такой же, как в решении @zRrr, только короче.